# Extrude acting like move blender 2.8

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to follow blender guru's tutorials as best I can in blender 2.8, but I've run into a problem while trying to make the coffee cup. I'm trying to use the extrude tool but instead of extruding the edge it acts like the move tool with proportional edit enabled, circle and all. I've attatched images to attempt to show what I mean:

Here is the original mug

1[image]

Here is after restarting blender and simply hitting E on the face I want to extrude, note that not shown here proportional edit is off but the ring for it appeared anyways.

[image]

And finally, here I scrolled until the ring was the size of the cursor. Note that here the face still isn't being extruded, as the set of faces that connect the ring of the mug are no longer flat, and are instead simply linking the two faces.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a known issue to other users. It may be patched in the next update. Until then, right-click after extruding with 'e' and use the 'g' key to move the face the desired amount. Change the orientation to Normal if necessary. Possible workaround is extruding from the menu instead, but I'm not certain about that